# AT&T 32-bit assembly does pushing strings after function call works?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att, shellcode

im currently trying to understand a AT&T 32-bit assembly code and i've stumbled upon these instructions and im trying to make sense out of them:

```
_start:
        jmp B

A:
   # fd = open("libtest.so.1.0", O_RDONLY);
   xorl %ecx, %ecx
   movb $5, %al
   popl %ebx
   xorl %ecx, %ecx
   int $0x80


B:
   call A
   .string "/lib/libtest.so.1.0"
```

A goes on for abit longer but it doesn't matter, my problem is within B, how is it possible to push the string after the call instruction was made? i don't see any way the string ended up in `ebx`  other than some sort of argument passing i don't understand yet.

Comment: Note that this code depends on EAX being 0 initially, otherwise `mov $5, %al` will leave garbage in the high bytes of the system-call number in EAX, if you used this in real shellcode instead of in _start in a static executable where regs start zeroed.  Using `lea 5(%ecx), %eax` costs 1 more byte, but fixes that problem.  (Or did you mean to `xor %eax,%eax` before `movb`?  You redundantly zero  ECX twice.  Another option is `xor %ecx,%ecx` / `mul %ecx` to zero ECX, EAX, and EDX.  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147775))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call` pushes the return address on stack, i.e. the address following the `call`, which would be the address of the path string here.

Normally a `ret` would then pop that off and return control to the caller, but here the code pops the address into `ebx` and uses it as a parameter for the interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Linux will start running the program from `_start` label which in turn its first line jump to `B`, `B` call `A` this will cause the processor to push return address of instruction after the call (which in this case is just address of string) onto the stack and then processor will go to `A` to execute instruction from there, `A` continue to execute instructions until it finishes but it doesn't return using `ret` instruction(which will cause popping return address from the stack and jumping to this address) so processor will just keep executing instructions in sequence as normal which means it will execute call instruction again (infinite loop).